# How to open a sent folder with html, css and js file in my vs code

Tags: javascript, html, css, photo

Someone sent me a folder holding an html, css and js file with photos, pls how do I take the folder to my vs code to open it ??

There was a way I accessed the folders in my computer from my vs code, but I didn’t see the folder, but if I go straight to my files I’d see it.

Guys, I really don’t just know, pls tell me what to do

Comment: Is it actually a folder, or is it a zip file?  You should be able to use "Open a Project" from the start window.

Comment: A zip file actually

Comment: You have to unzip that file in order to use it.

Comment: Oh... Like bring everything out of the file, right?

Comment: It would have been quicker to try it than to ask that question.....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Save the sent Folder to your computer.
Extract the zip folder in your computer.
Open VS Code

Goto: `File > OpenFolder` and select the path where you have saved your Folder. You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Cntrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Cntrl + O</kbd> to open.

If you are on windows machine, you can open Command Prompt in the folder you want to open and write `code .` this will open VS Code with current folder.

Comment: This doesn't help at all with a zip file.

Comment: It’s a zip file, pls what do I do?

Comment: Just exctract the zip file to any location and do the same as I have answered. I have also added the extract zip step in my answer.

Comment: If the answer helped you can accept the answer. That would be nice and helpful. Thanks.